# How to Add an shtml file to Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, shtml

I'm trying to pull in data from another site via an iFrame.  The other site requires that we have an shtml file within Wordpress using our vantage theme.  Wordpress doesn't have urls that end in .shtml  How can I add this file to wordpress?

Answer (score 0):

Since WordPress doesn't recognize this file type by default, you'll need to add it.

Append this to your functions.php file in your theme:

```php
function my_theme_custom_upload_mimes( $existing_mimes ) {
// add shtml to the list of mime types
$existing_mimes['shtml'] = 'text/html';

// return the array back to the function with our added mime type
return $existing_mimes;
}
add_filter( 'mime_types', 'my_theme_custom_upload_mimes' );
```

Comment: Thanks, but after adding that to the function.php file, how do I add the actual. newsletter.shtml file?

Comment: You should be able to upload the .shtml through the media library in Wordpress.